# Change encoding of androidManifest.xml to UTF-8 in Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio, encoding, android-manifest, android-studio-3.0

In the beta version of Android Studio 3 it seems that the androidManifest file is encoded forcefully into UTF-8 even if UTF-16 is stated in the header.
Is this a bug or is there another way now to change the encoding of the manifest back to UTF-8?

Comment: Rewrite the XML header to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app build process using gradle in Android Studio 3 (beta and RC-1) is using aapt2.

I compared the AndroidManifest.xml generated by the Android Studio 2.x (gradle version 2.3.x) and Adnroid Studio 3 Beta and RC-1 (gradle version 4.1). The result of the comparison is that with Android Studio 2.x the manifest encoding is `UTF-16LE` and with Android Studio 3 and the new tools, it is `UTF-8`... which happens to be the opposite of what you mentioned in the question above.

Using `android.enableAapt2=false` in the `gradle.properties` file, results in the build system using the old aapt.

More info: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html

**UPDATE:**

There is this tweet from yesterday (Oct 23rd) (https://twitter.com/the_very/status/922564040961826816):

> add `systemProp.file.encoding=UTF-8` to `gradle.properties` to fix all encoding problems in both local and server builds

It does work for me. I hope it helps you too.

Comment: Thank you for the clear up, I'll update my question.
Sadly, this doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: If your work is still pending and you wish to temporarily continue until a better solution/answer arrives, use the `android.enableAapt2=false`. Of course of you are not in a hurry, then never mind this comment :)

Comment: There is a tweet on Twitter related to this issue. Added it as a quote here.